# How to separate folders for constraints and validators classes in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

For some reason Symfony2 is trying to find my validator classes in the same folder as my constraints. Is it possible to separate them in different folders? In my case I'd like to have a `constraints` folder and a `validators` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the FQCN of the validator class by overriding `Constraint::validatedBy()`. This has to return the FQCN to the validator. By default, it contains:

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return get_class($this).'Validator';
}
```

That's why it's looking in the current directory for a validator.

Comment: what about this?:     
function getTargets() {
      self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT
}